# What is the difference between ImmutableArray<T>.As<TOther> and ImmutableArray<T>.CastArray<TOther> methods?

Tags: c#, .net-core, immutable-collections, immutablearray

I'm trying to understand the exact difference between the 3 following methods of the [ImmutableArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablearray-1?view=net-7.0) struct:

1. the static method [ImmutableArray<T>.CastUp<TDerived>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablearray-1.castup?view=net-7.0)
2. the instance method [ImmutableArray<T>.As<TOther>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablearray-1.as?view=net-7.0)
3. the instance method [ImmutableArray<T>.CastArray<TOther>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablearray-1.castarray?view=net-7.0)

I found myself studying these methods because I have the need to convert an existing instance of `ImmutableArray<TDerived>` to an instance of `ImmutableArray<TBase>`.
My scenario is similar to the following:

```
public interface IFoo {}

public sealed class Foo: IFoo {}

ImmutableArray<Foo> fooClassArray = GetFoos();

ImmutableArray<IFoo> fooInterfaceArray = // convert from fooClassArray instance
```

Based on my understanding, the way to do so efficiently is by using the [ImmutableArray<T>.CastUp<TDerived>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablearray-1.castup?view=net-7.0) static method. So, I could solve my problem this way:

```
ImmutableArray<IFoo> fooInterfaceArray = ImmutableArray<IFoo>.CastUp(fooClassArray);
```

If I get it correctly, by doing so there is **no need** to reallocate the underlying array: the array being wrapped by `fooClassArray` **is reused** and there is **no need** to allocate a brand new array for `fooInterfaceArray`.

First question: is my understanding about [ImmutableArray<T>.CastUp<TDerived>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablearray-1.castup?view=net-7.0) correct ?

By looking through the documentation for the [ImmutableArray<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablearray-1?view=net-7.0) struct I spotted the
[ImmutableArray<T>.As<TOther>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablearray-1.as?view=net-7.0) method and the [ImmutableArray<T>.CastArray<TOther>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablearray-1.castarray?view=net-7.0) method.

What is the difference between them ?

What is the intended usage of them ? It seems to me that they both solve the same use case.

Are they used to perform downcasts operations (as opposed to [ImmutableArray<T>.CastUp<TDerived>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablearray-1.castup?view=net-7.0), which is actually used to perform upcast operations) ?

Answer (score 3):

`CastUp` doesn't copy the array, as you said. It is very efficient to use, as long as each element is trivially castable to a base type. Note that boxing or converting don't count as trivially casting (ie trying to use that to change `int` to `long` will fail):

```
    public static ImmutableArray<T> CastUp<TDerived>(ImmutableArray<TDerived> items)
        where TDerived : class?, T
    {
        return new ImmutableArray<T>(items.array);
    }
```

`CastArray` seems to simply cast the entire array to the type you ask. It can work with covariance, so it should be more or less equivalent to the first function (again, boxing doesn't count). Be careful of the parameter type however, it is not an `ImmutableArray`:

```
    public ImmutableArray<TOther> CastArray<TOther>() where TOther : class?
    {
        return new ImmutableArray<TOther>((TOther[])(object)array!);
    }
```

`As` is the generalization of `CastUp`, allowing you to also cast down, at a cost:

```
    public ImmutableArray<TOther> As<TOther>() where TOther : class?
    {
        return new ImmutableArray<TOther>((this.array as TOther[]));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding about `ImmutableArray<T>.CastUp<TDerived>` method is good. This method that returns a new `ImmutableArray<TDerived>` that is a copy of the original `ImmutableArray<T>` with the elements cast to TDerived using the as operator.

In summary, `CastUp<TDerived>` is used when you want to convert an `ImmutableArray<T>` to an `ImmutableArray<TDerived>` where T is a base class or interface and TDerived is a derived class, and you want to handle the case where an element of the original array cannot be explicitly converted to TDerived by setting it to null in the resulting array.

Regarding the methods `ImmutableArray<T>.As<TOther>` and `ImmutableArray<T>.CastArray<TOther>`, `As<TOther>` is used when you want to convert an `ImmutableArray<T>` to an `ImmutableArray<TOther>` and you are certain that all elements of the original array can be explicitly converted to TOther.

Here is an example of using `As<TOther>`:

```
ImmutableArray<int> array = ImmutableArray.Create(1, 2, 3);
ImmutableArray<double> doubleArray = array.As<double>();

Console.WriteLine(doubleArray[0]);  // Output: 1
```

`CastArray<TOther>` is used when you want to convert an `ImmutableArray<T>` to an `ImmutableArray<TOther>` and you are not certain that all elements of the original array can be explicitly converted to TOther, and you want to handle the case where an element cannot be converted by setting it to null in the resulting array.

Here is an example of using `CastArray<TOther>`:

```
ImmutableArray<object> array = ImmutableArray.Create(1, "2");
ImmutableArray<int> intArray = array.CastArray<int>();

console.WriteLine(intArray[0]);  // Output: 1
console.WriteLine(intArray[1]);  // Output: null
```